# Can git track that certain lines were copied from another file?

Tags: git, git-log

First, I have file abc.java, and it has 10 lines of code. Then, in the same commit, I remove those lines from abc.java and put them in xyz.java. Is there a way that `git blame` or `git log` can follow the history of those lines across files?

Here is what I'm wanting. I want to do `git log -L100,110:xyz.java` ([see -L documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_options)), and not only see all commits touching those 10 lines in xyz.java, but also all the commits that changed those lines when they were in abc.java.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Git is only able to track every file individually (it will create a hash for every file). Git will try to assume if a file/folder has been renamed (it will have the same hash). This means, though, that tracking of individual lines is not possible.

Comment: hmm. I'm not sure if that's exactly accurate. Git can algorithmically detect renames by taking two blobs and determining if the percentage of similarity between the two surpasses some threshold. Therefore it's not necessary for renamed file to be the exact same file and hash. See the "--find-renames" argument to [git log](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log).   Either way though, it appears that what I am after is not possible. I can either follow renames, or follow lines within a file, but not both at the same time :(. ie, `git log --follow -L...` throws an error.